# Bulider Design Pattern to make generic method for methods having large number of parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an interface `Itest` and `ClassA` & `ClassB` are implementing this interface. `testA` & `testB` are methods in these classes respectively.

```
testA(String a, String b, String c, D d, E e)

testB(String a, String b, String c, F f, G g)
```

*Here `D`, `E`, `F`, `G` are custom data types (related to databases)*. I simplified the methods actually they have more number of parameters.

I need to make a generic method in `testAB` in `Itest` interface and implement that in both classes rather than having their own method.

```
testAB(String a, String b, String c, D d, E e, F f, G g)
```

As the number of parameters is more, generic method `testAB` will be pain for the user as he has to pass so many `null` values.

- Is this a usecase for **Bulider Design Pattern**?
- If yes, how to achieve this using this design pattern?

Comment: is it possible to have ClassX and ClassY in future with own parameters?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker did not get you. ClassX?

Comment: I mean you have two classes in your example. Maybe in future you will have four classes or more?

Comment: yes it may vary in future.

Comment: Can you group `D`, `E`, `F`, or `G` in a logical manner? For example, if you had `testA(a, b, databaseHost, databasePort, username, password, databaseName)`, you could change that to `testA(a, b, ConnectionParameters)` and have `ConnectionParameters` contain `username`, `password`, `databaseHost`, `databasePort`, `databaseName`.

Comment: @Zymus your suggestion is nice. But it does not fit in my use case.

Comment: @dev I understand that you are not new here but it would be great if you can comment on existing answers and let us know what's lacking in the answer or accept one of the answers. Alternately, you can post an answer if you feel that none of the answers have met your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the core requirement that you have is that you don't want the client to be passing additional parameters when they are not required. You can solve your problem using plain old method `overloading` :

Alter your `ITest` interface to have a single method called `test`

```
public interface ITest {
     public void test(String a,String b,String c,D d,E e,F f,G g);
}
```

Alter `A` as follows :

```
public class A implements ITest {

     //this is an overload - v1
     public void test(String a,String b,String c,D d,E e) {
            //dispatch the call to the overriden method
            test(a,b,c,d,e,null,null);
     }

     //this is an overload - v2
     public void test(String a,String b,String c,E e,F f) {
           //dispatch the call to the overriden method
           test(a,b,c,null,null,e,f);
     }

     @Override
     //this is an overriden method - v3
     public void test(String a,String b,String c,D d,E e,F f,G g) {
            if(d!=null && e!=null) {
                //use a,b,c,d,e and do something
            } 

            if(f!=null && g!=null) {
                //use a,b,c,f,g and do something
            }
     }
}
```

Now the client code can call whichever overloaded form they want without the need to pass `null`. Your overloaded methods will simply dispatch the call to a common method (which gives you the advantage of code reuse):

```
classAObj.test("1","2","3",new D(),new E());//calls overloaded method - v1
classAObj.test("1","2","3",new F(),new G());//calls overloaded method - v2
classAObj.test("1","2","3",new D(),new E(),new F(),new G());//calls overriden method - v3
```

Notice how the client code does not have to worry about passing additional parameters when they are not required. Also notice how clean the client calls look. Similar changes can be made in `B` as well.

---

<sub>1. You have an option to make `ITest` an abstract class. This will allow you to make the `test` method in it have the `protected` access specifier. The reason for wanting a `protected` access specifier is to restrict client classes from being able to access the method and always go through the overloaded forms instead. This is an add-on feature you can consider implementing in the future if you are stuck with using an `interface` at the moment.</sub>

<sub>2. You could also take advantage of `Generics` to avoid the need to write a new class every-time a new object type is introduced but as you can see from the other answers, this can easily complicate your code to a great extent. You could also add the overloaded methods to `ITest` interface to make it a part of its contract. However, I am deliberately leaving these parts out of my answer because the crux of your problem can be solved by using `overloading`.</sub>

<sub>3. The `Builder` pattern is a creational pattern. It's an overkill in this particular case since classes such as `D`,`E`,`F` and `G` are domain objects. Class `A` and `B` don't really depend on them in the real sense but use them as a source of data instead.</sub>

Comment: you explained things very well, but I need to work on existing code having interface.

Comment: @dev I have edited my answer to use an `interface` instead of an `abstract` class. The use of `abstract` class is optional. Also note that my answer makes your code clean and easy to read. Messy code that can't be understood even by the developer who wrote it is pretty pointless

Comment: You claim that the builder pattern is unreadable for multiple parameters but though propose a methodology where you clumb up each and every parameter that ever could be passed to the method parameter set - even when you don't really use them. Imagine you have overloaded a method like 50 times already (we don't know the exact needs of the OP) and you are adding a further parameter - you need so adapt each overloaded method to nullify this additional parameter. Furthermore, what happens if two tests have parameters of equal types? You need to take logic into the overloaded methods as well.

Comment: Furthermore, I have had a couple of situations in the past where already 4-5 parameters led to a situation where I was not sure if parameter x was on position 3 or 4 or 5 and therefore had to first look up some documentation - and test-code often has no documentation at all - this is where builder patterns actually increase readability compared to overall long parameter lists - but I guess we should stop arguing any further on that particular issue. The OP should decide on his own what approach fits best for his needs.

Comment: @RomanVottner I am pretty much aware that the very problem that the `Builder` pattern solves is to avoid `telescoping` methods or constructors. I am also aware that remembering parameter positions is a big no no. That does not mean that you should always use `Builder` pattern in such situations. All the problems that you point out with my answer can easily be solved using `polymorphism`. Explaining this in my answer would make my answer very long. The crux of my solution is method overloading which is what I wanted to highlight in my answer. Anything more than this would be spoon-feeding.

Comment: We could go on and on with this discussion :) The example I presented also uses overloaded methods, just to point that out. In addition to that you don't need to remember any parameter orderings and can easily define optional parameters and if styled correctly increases readability - more so if you return after a couple of month to that code and don't know what all the parameters would have been. I also stated before that a builder pattern simply can be replaced by a POJO declaration - but obviously (relating to the comments section) this does not suite the OP at all. So enough advocated

Answer (score 2):

Yep here you could use the builder pattern.
You would like to have objects holding the information passed to your methods.

These objects could be created with an internal builder, while the fields may hold default values. Here a small example how this could look like.

```
ParamTestA<D, E> paramA = new ParamTestA<>.Builder(a, b, c).setD(d).setE(e).build();

testA(paramA);
```

Comment: What you used here is rather a `Parameter Object` design pattern where you create the parameter object using a builder pattern.

Comment: Hm I'm not aware of such a design pattern. In this case the object is more likely a POJO which is build using the builder pattern and then (ab)used as a parameter holder.

Comment: If you replace the builder pattern with a traditional POJO instantiation, you would still end up having the same POJO. The [Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) simply refactors all method parameters into a singe object. That's why the actual pattern used here is the parameter object - but this is just to name things right.

Answer (score 2):

Feels like you trying to do something wrong:

First you want a method with lots of generic parameters in your interface

```
interface ITest<D,E,F,G> {
   void test(String a, D d, E e, F f, G g)
}
```

This is wrong because your interface is tightly coupled with implementation details

If you will try to abstract from difference in method parameters

```
interface ITest {
   void test(String a, Map<String, Object> params);
}
```

you will get what you want, but you will loose generic type check.

Anyway I will recommend you this variant, because you are responsible for passing parameters to your method.

Comment: What's stopping the client from passing a `Dog` object to the params map? Imagine the amount of `instanceof` checks and casts in the `test` method that will be required due to this? Example : `if(params.get("E") instanceof `E`) { ((E)params.get("E")).getFieldOnlyPresentInE() }`

Comment: I expected that person who passes params to methods and receives params in test is the same person. Obviously this solution will not work, if this actions are not related.

Answer (score 1):

**Parameter Object through Builder-Pattern**

First and foremost, The builder pattern is kind of an instance factory where you get a simple POJO as a result after calling `.build()` or something similar to that on the builders instance.

The builder therefore follows often this kind of syntax:

```
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass.Builder<>(requiredArgument).optionalArgumentX(x).build();
```

This pattern often goes hand in hand with a limited scope (`private` or `protected`) of the constructor of the concrete object, but does not insist on that.

Although Timo has already given an example where you can use a combination of the `Parameter Object` and `Builder` patterns, writing a builder which collects arguments already captured by an other builder before may lead to plenty of copy& paste code (don't repeat yourself).

I've therefore come up with a parental builder setup which might be of interest to you especially if you might need to extend the generated parameter object in future.

The core of this extensible builder pattern is an abstract `TestParam` class which has also an abstract builder defined.

```
public abstract class TestParam<Z>
{
    public static abstract class CommonBuilder<T extends CommonBuilder<T, Z>, Z>
    {
        protected final String a;
        protected final String b;
        protected final String c;
        protected Z z = null;

        public CommonBuilder(String a, String b, String c) 
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public T withOptionalZ(Z z)
        {
            this.z = z;
            return (T)this;
        }

        public abstract <T> T build();
    }

    protected final String name;
    protected final String a;
    protected final String b;
    protected final String c;
    protected Z z = null;

    protected TestParam(String name, String a, String b, String c)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    protected TestParam(String name, String a, String b, String c, Z z)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public String getA() 
    {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public String getC()
    {
        return c;
    }

    protected abstract String getContent();

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name+"[A: " + a + ", B: " + b + ", C: " + c + (z != null ? ", Z: " + z.toString() : "") + getContent() +"]";
    }
}
```

This abstract class have all the common parameters (`a`, `b` and `c`) found in your example and an additional optional parameter `z` whose type can be passed generically. Except from the abstract definition most of the stuff should be straight forward. The definition of the generic builder type is so that we can actually create proper child classes via child builders.

A child class (including a child builder) can now look like this:

```
public class TestParamA<D,E,Z> extends TestParam<Z>
{
    public static class Builder<T extends TestParamA<D,E,Z>, B extends TestParamA.Builder<? extends TestParamA<D,E,Z>, ? extends B, D,E,Z>, D,E,Z> extends TestParam.CommonBuilder<TestParamA.Builder<?,?, D,E,Z>, Z>
    {
        protected D d;
        protected E e;

        public Builder(String a, String b, String c)
        {
            super(a, b, c);
        }

        public B withD(D d)
        {
            this.d = d;
            return (B)this;
        }

        public B withE(E e)
        {
            this.e = e;
            return (B)this;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T build()
        {
            TestParamA t = new TestParamA("TestParamA", a, b, c, z, d, e);
            return (T)t;
        }        
    }

    protected final D d;
    protected final E e;

    protected TestParamA(String name, String a, String b, String c, Z z, D d, E e)
    {
        super(name, a, b, c, z);
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
    }

    public D getD()
    {
        return d;
    }

    public E getE()
    {
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContent()
    {
        return ", D: " + d + ", E: " + e;
    }
}
```

Here most of the stuff is quite simple except for the generic type definition:

```
Builder<T extends TestParamA<D,E,Z>, 
        B extends TestParamA.Builder<? extends TestParamA<D,E,Z>, ? extends B, D,E,Z>, 
        D,E,Z> 
    extends TestParam.CommonBuilder<TestParamA.Builder<?,?, D,E,Z>, Z>
```

- `T` is the type of the object to create via the builder (`TestParamA`, `TestParamB`, ...)
- `B` is the current instance of the builder which creates the parameter object. This looks rather complicated but gurantees that the child-builder is used and not fallback to the parent-builder if you use a method from the parent-builder.
- `D`, `E`, `Z` are the actual types of the parameters passed to the builder

I don't post `TestParamB` here as this is almost identical to `TestParamA` except that it defines builder-operations `withF(...)` and `withG(...)` instead of `withD(...)` and `withE(...)` and also prints the `F` and `G` equivalent output.

You have now a couple of options to use your builder in conjunction with method declarations. As I'm not sure which method is best suited for you, I've created a small test-case with multiple different invocations:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        TestParamA<D,E,?> a = new TestParamA.Builder<>("a","b","c").withD(new D()).withE(new E()).build();
        TestParamB<F,G,String> b = new TestParamB.Builder<>("a","b","c").withF(new F()).withG(new G()).withOptionalZ("z").build();
        TestParam<String> c = new TestParamA.Builder<>("a","b","c").withD(new D()).withE(new E()).withOptionalZ("z").build();
        TestParam d = new TestParamB.Builder<>("a","b","c").withF(new F()).withG(new G()).build();

        test(a);
        test(b);
        test(c);
        test(d);
        test(new TestParamA.Builder<>("a","b","c").withD(new D()).withE(new E()));
        test(new TestParamB.Builder<>("a","b","c").withF(new F()).withG(new G()).withOptionalZ("z"));
        testCommon(new TestParamA.Builder<>("a","b","c").withD(new D()).withE(new E()).withOptionalZ("z"));
        testCommon(new TestParamB.Builder<>("a","b","c").withF(new F()).withG(new G()));
    }

    public static void test(TestParamA<?,?,?> testParam)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for ParamA: " + testParam.toString());
    }

    public static void test(TestParamB<?,?,?> testParam)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for ParamB: " + testParam.toString());
    }

    public static void test(TestParam<?> testParam)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for Param: " + testParam.toString());
    }

    public static void test(TestParamA.Builder<?,?,?,?,?> builder)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for BuilderA: " + builder.build().toString());
    }

    public static void test(TestParamB.Builder<?,?,?,?,?> builder)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for BuilderB: " + builder.build().toString());
    }

    public static void testCommon(TestParam.CommonBuilder<?,?> builder)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for CommonBuilder: " + builder.build().toString());
    }
}
```

On running this test class the following output should be returned:

```
Test for ParamA: TestParamA[A: a, B: b, C: c, D: D, E: E]
Test for ParamB: TestParamB[A: a, B: b, C: c, Z: z, F: F, G: G]
Test for Param: TestParamA[A: a, B: b, C: c, Z: z, D: D, E: E]
Test for Param: TestParamB[A: a, B: b, C: c, F: F, G: G]
Test for BuilderA: TestParamA[A: a, B: b, C: c, D: D, E: E]
Test for BuilderB: TestParamB[A: a, B: b, C: c, Z: z, F: F, G: G]
Test for CommonBuilder: TestParamA[A: a, B: b, C: c, Z: z, D: D, E: E]
Test for CommonBuilder: TestParamB[A: a, B: b, C: c, F: F, G: G]
```

`new D()` and the other classes created with `new` are just simple POJOs which return their simple class name in `toString()`.

As can be seen each invoked test-method contains the appropriate child parameter object created through the corresponding builder. For more general methods like `test(TestParam<?> testParam)` or `testCommon(...)` you might need to cast the parameter object to the concrete class before actually gaining access to those methods (`getD()`, ...) unique to the concrete classes - but I guess you are familiar with that concept anyway.

**CONS**

- Writing a builder creates additional overhead compared to a traditional constructor call
- Creating a new instance also comes with additional costs of extra characters to type

**PROS**

- Flexible order of parameters possible. Usually you don't have to remember the order of parameters, which is quite nice if you deal with more than 5+ parameters. Required parameters, though, are often specified within the constructor of the builder and therefore require a fixed order, unless they can be specified using builder-methods.
- Supports grouping of related parameters (like `.dimensions(int x, int y, int width, int height)`)
- Type safty
- Extensibility (as showcased in this post)
- Generated types can be used as `Parameter Objects` and thus rely on polymorphism if the created objects follow a parent-child structure
- Increased readability support. Although argued in the comments of this post, builders increase readability if you return to the code month later and have to remember what all those parameters passed were. Builders add some kind of lexical semantic to the parameters. Readability can be thus increased by structuring the fluent method calls appropriately

**When (not) to use Builders**

That being said, builders are nice but also come with overhead. You should not use them if there are only few parameters or many different independent types should be created as a builder needs to be set up for each type. Here a simple POJO instantiation for the first case and a general factory pattern for the latter case is superior IMO.

If your approach needs to be as flexible as possible and you don't need to rely on type safety or provide some internal type extraction mechanism (like Camel's type converters), use `Map<String, Object>` as parameter object instead. Camel uses this approach for its message headers. Also the Activiti BPMN engine uses this approach. (explained by AdamSkywalker in this thread)

If you have a limited number of scenarios and a clear number of parameters, use simple method overloading (as explained by Chetan Kinger).

If you struggle with remembering the exact order of parameters over time, there might be some kind of class extension going on in the future or if you have a bunch of optional parameters (maybe even with some default values) builders come in nicely.

Comment: you deserved a cookie

Comment: Unbelievable efforts. Kudos to you.That being said. the API that you propose is very unreadable. For instance, the call `test(new TestParamA.Builder<>("a","b","c").withD(new D()).withE(new E()));` with just two objects `D` and `E` itself will make the user of the API a bit dizzy. Imagine what happens when the number of parameters is 10? Should the client code really be doing so much work?

Comment: @ChetanKinger you can pass multiple parameters with a single method also (grouping parameters), this example just did not specify them. You have to decide on your own what suits you best. Builder patterns are useful if you have multiple parameters as the order of parameters is quite flexible with builders and you still have compile time check security compared to maps. On top of that you gain readability if you style your code therefore (not as done in this sample)

Comment: @RomanVottner I don't think the OP is looking for a solution that requires wrapping the parameters into an object (That is, grouping parameters). Also, as explained in my answer, the builder pattern is kind of an overkill as it makes the code extremely unreadable and makes client code do a lot of work in this particular case.

Comment: @ChetanKinger First, the OP asked if this is possible with a builder-pattern (assuming he knows what a builder pattern is he probably also aimed for a parameter-object approach). Next, you mix up parameter-grouping with the parameter-object by itself. The builder may have a method `.withDimensions(int x, int y, int width, int height)` and a method to specify the color `.withColor(Color c)` - grouping here logically groups parameters that often go hand in hand - of course all parameters are wrapped in the final object per se.

Comment: `(T)this`, `(B)this` are unsafe casts.

Comment: The compiler claims it is unsafe, but how can it be unsafe if the generic definition asserts that the type has to be either the builder type in case of B or one of its extension classes? Moreover, the cast guarantees that on invoking the builder method of an extension-class the builder does not fallback to the CommonBuilder and therefore prevents further invocations of the extension builder methods - think about it.