# making interface when methods have different parameters

Tags: java, interface

I was recently making a small program that involves wrapping around a JFreeChart library and made a number of convenience classes to easily make the charts and provide ready objects that exted JPanel and can readily be placed around and realised that all the classes have basically the same functionality and very similar parameters. It does make sense to me to make an interface and make each of the classes implement it, however there is a small hickup.

Each type of chart requires slightly different parameter set as for example piechart doesn't care about the time axis, bar chart has very distinctive time points, line chart pretends to be real time, etc.

I know that a parameter can be specified as a generic type in the interface and defined as concrete type in the implementation of the method, but I have never seen a variable number of parameters, so I created numer of overloaded methods and this got me thinking:

What is the "correct" way to do it?

1. like I did it (the lazy way) - define every method as overload in the interface and make unused methods throw an exception when called in a wrong class.
2. Make a container object and pass it (Seems like a waste of resources to pass object containing for example time series data for a pie chart)
3. Drop use of interface completely as it does not fit in that case perfectly and make separate classes that are just very similar.
4. Something else?

I would like justification of answer if you suggest one option or another.
My justification for going with 1. is that it makes the purpose very explicit, but it does seem like a violation of principles behind interface.

Comment: I would use Builder Pattern for parameters

Comment: My two cents... use varargs. May be you can have the first parameter as an enum that states what type and second parameter would be a vararg of Objects - does not offer type safety, but solves the problem with limited code.

Comment: it's not a matter of too many parameters, but the fact that many of them are case specific, so I don't think the builder will solve my question. Vararg may be a way to go, but again - it would be safer to pass a container class as the only argument and extract the needed data from it?

Comment: What about defining a base interface with all the methods having the same parameters, and extending it to special interfaces for the "special" diagram types?

Comment: @PavanKumar this requires to check each parameter for `instanceof` and assign each field its value in a predefined order. Therefore, providing a Map is supperior in that case. To be as generic as possible but though have compile saftiness, you can use parameter objects and even use inheritance among instances. The builder pattern is just a way to create them ([sample which uses inheritance within builders and their created objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639947/bulider-design-pattern-to-make-generic-method-for-methods-having-large-number-of/30645203#30645203))