# Using generics in non-static inner class

Tags: java, android, generics

```
public abstract class OuterClass<OT extends OuterClass<OT>> {
    public <C extends OuterClass<?>> C parse(Class<C> clazz) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(this)) {
            return (C) this;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public abstract class InnerClass<CT extends InnerClass<CT> {
        public <C extends InnerClass<?>> C parse(Class<C> clazz) {
            if (clazz.isInstance(this)) {
                return (C) this;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}

OuterClass<?> oInstance;
InnerClass<?> iInstance;
```

In the above example the `iInstance` variable works fine. However the `iInstance` variable shows an error when adding the generics part

> Type arguments given on a raw type

If I remove the generics part from variables, then the below test cases will fail with type errors

```
public class ExtendedOuter extends OuterClass<ExtendedOuter> {

}

// This only works on OuterClass<?> and not on OuterClass
ExtendedOuter eInstance = oInstance.parse(ExtendedOuter.class);
```

> Found: OuterClass, required: ExtendedOuter

This is no problem on static/outer classes as they can be defined as `ClassName<?>`, but non-static inner classes cannot be defined with `<?>`

How can I add `<?>` to `iInstance` without making `InnerClass` static?

**EDIT:**
Let me give some examples why these classes uses their extended versions as generic.

```
public abstract class OuterClass<OT extends OuterClass<OT>> {
    public abstract OT returnMe();
}

public class ExtendedOuter extends OuterClass<ExtendedOuter> {
    @Override
    public ExtendedOuter returnMe() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The above for an example would not work if I simply made the return type `OuterClass` on the abstract version. If so, any extended versions would have to be casted whenever this method was used, which does not seam ideal.

Also just got an error from AndroidStudio as well after removing `<CT>` in `<T extends OuterClass<CT>>`

> The parameter OT is not within it's bound

This error is shown in extended classes when doing `ClassName extends OuterClass<ClassName>`. In other words it will not work just using `<T extends OuterClass>` on the abstract classes.

Comment: Your inner class is extending a type of itself??

Comment: `public abstract class OuterClass<OT extends OuterClass<CT>>` -  it seems pretty difficult to find a concrete type for the parameter `OT` for which this would work. The parameter would have to derive from `OuterClass`, which has a type parameter that has to derive again from `OuterClass`. How can you fulfill that in a finite type? `OuterClass<OuterClass<OuterClass<...>>>`?

Comment: My real base classes have abstract methods where the return type is itself. These types should be replaced with the type of any class extending from it. By using OT as a return type in the base class, this is possible. I can see that AndroidStudio allows me to use (T extends ClassName), but Eclipse would fail if I did not use (T extends ClassName<T>)

Comment: In any case, changing (T extends ClassName<T>) to (T extends ClassName) does not fix anything

Comment: "How can I add <?> to iInstance without making InnerClass static?", try: OuterClass<?>.InnerClass<?> iInstance;

Comment: That's a great suggestion, but I have already tried that and it does not work. My solution was to make the abstract inner class static as I really only need the extended versions to be non-static. But it still bugs me that this is not possible.

Comment: `OuterClass<OT extends OuterClass<CT>>` what is `CT`? `<OT extends OuterClass<OT>>` is okay, but `CT` does not exist nor is it defined.

Comment: Just a typing error in my example. It should be OT in the first and CT in the second class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639947/bulider-design-pattern-to-make-generic-method-for-methods-having-large-number-of/30645203#30645203) I did which showcased a builder patter which uses generic types and inheritance to reduce the actual code in inheritance cases, this is also possible for none-static classes. I therefore modified the builder example accordingly to avoid static inner-classes:

Parent class with parent builder:

```
public abstract class TestParam<Z>
{
    public abstract class CommonBuilder<T extends CommonBuilder<T>>
    {
        protected final String a;
        protected final String b;
        protected final String c;
        protected Z z = null;

        public CommonBuilder(String a, String b, String c) 
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T withOptionalZ(Z z)
        {
            this.z = z;
            return (T)this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
        public abstract <T> T build();
    }

    protected String name;
    protected String a;
    protected String b;
    protected String c;
    protected Z z = null;

    protected TestParam() {

    }

    protected TestParam(String name, String a, String b, String c)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    protected TestParam(String name, String a, String b, String c, Z z)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public String getA() 
    {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public String getC()
    {
        return c;
    }

    protected abstract String getContent();

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name+"[A: " + a + ", B: " + b + ", C: " + c + (z != null ? ", Z: " + z.toString() : "") + getContent() +"]";
    }
}
```

A child class with a none-static builder looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"hiding", "unchecked"})
public class TestParamA<D,E,Z> extends TestParam<Z>
{
    public class Builder<T extends TestParamA<D,E,Z>, 
                         B extends TestParamA<D,E,Z>.Builder<? extends TestParamA<D,E,Z>, ? extends B, D, E>, 
                         D,E> 
                 extends TestParam<Z>.CommonBuilder<Builder<TestParamA<D,E,Z>,B, D,E>>
    {
        protected D d;
        protected E e;

        public Builder(String a, String b, String c)
        {
            super(a, b, c);
        }

        public B withD(D d)
        {
            this.d = d;
            return (B)this;
        }

        public B withE(E e)
        {
            this.e = e;
            return (B)this;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T build()
        {
            TestParamA<D,E,Z> t = new TestParamA<>("TestParamA", a, b, c, z, d, e);
            return (T)t;
        }        
    }

    protected D d;
    protected E e;

    public TestParamA() {
        super();
    }

    protected TestParamA(String name, String a, String b, String c, Z z, D d, E e)
    {
        super(name, a, b, c, z);
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
    }

    public D getD()
    {
        return d;
    }

    public E getE()
    {
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContent()
    {
        return ", D: " + d + ", E: " + e;
    }
}
```

To test the functionality of this outer/inner classes you can implement something like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        TestParamA<D,E,String> a = new TestParamA<>().new Builder<>("a","b","c").withD(new D()).withE(new E()).build();
        TestParamB<F,G,String> b = new TestParamB<>().new Builder<>("a","b","c").withF(new F()).withG(new G()).withOptionalZ("z").build();
        TestParam<String> c = new TestParamA<>().new Builder<>("a","b","c").withD(new D()).withE(new E()).withOptionalZ("z").build();
        TestParam<?> d = new TestParamB<>().new Builder<>("a","b","c").withF(new F()).withG(new G()).build();

        test(a);
        test(b);
        test(c);
        test(d);

        TestParam<?>.CommonBuilder<? extends TestParam<?>.CommonBuilder<?>> builder = 
            new TestParamA<>().new Builder<>("a", "b", "c").withD(new D()).withE(new E());
        test(builder);
        // or a bit shorter
        TestParam<?>.CommonBuilder<?> builder2 = 
            new TestParamB<>().new Builder<>("a", "b", "c").withF(new F()).withG(new G());
        test(builder2);
    }

    public static void test(TestParamA<?,?,?> testParam)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for ParamA: " + testParam.toString());
    }

    public static void test(TestParamB<?,?,?> testParam)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for ParamB: " + testParam.toString());
    }

    public static void test(TestParam<?> testParam)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for Param: " + testParam.toString());
    }

    public static void test(TestParam<?>.CommonBuilder<?> builder)
    {
        System.out.println("Test for CommonBuilder: " + builder.build().toString());
    }
}
```

`TestParamB` is identical to `TestParamA` - it only contains varialbe and builder-methods for `F` and `G` instead of `D` and `E`. Furthermore, `D`, `E`, `F` and `G` are only classes with a simple `toString()` implementation which returns just the simple classname.

This will print the following output:

```
Test for ParamA: TestParamA[A: a, B: b, C: c, D: D, E: E]
Test for ParamB: TestParamB[A: a, B: b, C: c, Z: z, F: F, G: G]
Test for Param: TestParamA[A: a, B: b, C: c, Z: z, D: D, E: E]
Test for Param: TestParamB[A: a, B: b, C: c, F: F, G: G]
Test for CommonBuilder: TestParamA[A: a, B: b, C: c, D: D, E: E]
Test for CommonBuilder: TestParamB[A: a, B: b, C: c, F: F, G: G]
```

Comment: The problem is not getting non-static inner classes to work. It's getting is to work defining generic type when defining them as a datatype. Try doing `CommonBuilder<?> builder;` and you will get an error.

Comment: @DanielB updated the post to include samples for declaring a `builder` variable and assigning a new instance to it

Comment: I tried that, but in AndroidStudio I get an error when trying this. Maybe this is simply an editor issue.

Comment: @DanielB I've tested the code on NetBeans 7.4 (Java 7), Eclipse Kepler Release 2 (Java 7) and IntelliJ 14.1.4 Ultimate (Java 7&8) - the test compiles and runs on all 3 IDEs without any issues, however, IntelliJ does show up an error that the parameter is not within its bounds - this also seems to be the case with your AndroidStudio IDE. However, if I change the definition to `TestParamA<D,E,String> a = new TestParamA<D,E,String>().new Builder<TestParamA<D,E,String>, TestParamA<D,E,String>.Builder<?,?,D,E>,D,E>("a", "b", "c").withD(new D()).withE(new E()).build();` IntelliJ is fine with that

Comment: In `(T)this` and `(B)this` you are making unsafe casts.

Comment: It might be better to use a simpler structure using static inner classes in these cases. This ends up in a lot of generics definitions.

Answer (score 0):

> However the iInstance variable shows an error when adding the generics
>   part
>
> Type arguments given on a raw type

First of all, that's not the problem you should be getting, because `InnerClass` is not defined in the scope. Being an inner class, it is scoped inside the outer class's scope. So when it is outside the outer class, you need to explicitly qualify it with an outer class, or it will give you a `InnerClass` symbol not found error. So you are not showing your real code (maybe you have another `InnerClass` somewhere) or not show your real error.

> If I remove the generics part from variables, then the below test
>   cases will fail with type errors

When you use a raw type to access members, that turns off all generics on those members. So `.parse()` is erased to `public OuterClass parse(Class clazz)` (this is true even though `CT` is not used by the method), and that's why `oInstance.parse(ExtendedOuter.class)` returns type `OuterClass` which is not compatible with `ExtendedOuter`.

> How can I add `<?>` to iInstance without making InnerClass static?

Like `OuterClass<?>.InnerClass<?>`, or `OuterClass<Something>.InnerClass<SomethingElse>`